# volitional + negative verb special meaning or kimarimonku

Tags: negation, volitional-form

I was reading a Japanese manga and came across the sentence: よそうかんがえるな。。。

Now, I took this to mean "Stop, let's not think about it", but I am wondering if the phrase is a set-phrase or it is similar to volitional+omou which means to plan.

Please let me know, because it is really bothering me.

Comment: Do you have surrounding context, or an actual picture?

Comment: HE  was thinking of the girl he liked and had to stop thinking in order to pay attention in class.  he was being distracted by thought.

Comment: Then isn't there any spacing or line break between よそう and かんがえるな? Is trailing 。。。 appearing as it is in the original text?

Comment: i typed it as it shows.

Comment: Hmm... That's not really what I expected. Could you add sentences come before and after that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is surely 予想を考えるな with を omitted, meaning, "Don't speculate".

[予想を考える](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E4%BA%88%E6%83%B3%E3%82%92%E8%80%83%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%22) seems to be commonly used in relation to speculation about things like horse racing, as in e.g. 競馬の予想を考える.

Comment: なんでやねん！w しかもなんでUV入ってんねん！ｗ

Comment: No, that makes no sense.

Comment: "that really makes a lot of sense" >> Lol you gotta be kidding or being sarcastic @MD-4

Answer (score 1):

All I can say for sure is that:

> 「よそうかんがえるな」

is ***not*** a set phrase.  It is not even normal writing.

If it were meant to be:

> 「よそう、[考]{かんが}えるな・・・」 or even 「よそう、かんがえるな・・・」 in all kana,

then, it would be much better writing and it makes perfect sense as well.  It would mean something like:

> "Nah, let's not!  Don't (even) think about it!"

That is, however, still not a set phrase.